# iOS - UICollectoinView - how to make parent view scroll seamlessly into child UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm wondering what the best way to put about 1-2 pages worth of content above a custom infinite grid UICollectionView, and have it all scroll together seamlessly?

At this point I'm considering making all of my content above the grid be a supplementaryView of the collectionView. Is that the best way? It would seem to me that it would be nicer to have that content that's not truly part of the collection at all be outside of the collectionView.

Perhaps there's a better way to have the scroll event share between the parent scrollView and the child collectionView?

Comment: It is hard to say what you are trying to accomplish.  Could you provide more detail?  Certainly you can have any number of independent views be contained in the scrollView that holds your collectionView.  iOS keeps track of which view should handle the scroll event.